JWT Token still accepted after expiry Spring Boot 3.2 OAuth2 resource server
I am learning how to use JWT to build a Stateless backend API, This is a dummy learning project.
I am using Spring Boot's OAuth 2 resource server.
Since I just have a single backend, there is no need for public keys, I just have one secret key generated with openssl and appended to the application.properties file.
The documentation has not been good to say the least and it has taken a long time to figure out basic things.
I have managed to successfully log the users through a basic UsernamePasswordAuthentication and then issued a token that for testing purposes should expire in 2 minutes.
However, it is still valid many times for up to 10 minutes after the expiry, Why is this ?
Here is the code:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MuserDetailsService muserDetailsService;

    private JwtPropHolder jwtPropHolder;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtPropHolder jwtPropHolder) {
        this.jwtPropHolder = jwtPropHolder;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain createSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> {
                configurer.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> {
                    jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(getMyJwtAuthenticationConverter());
                });
            })

            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder createPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder createJwtDecoder() {

        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(jwtPropHolder.getSecretKey()).build();

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withClockSkwe = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(
            new JwtTimestampValidator(Duration.ofSeconds(0))
        );

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withClockSkwe);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager(JwtDecoder jwtDecoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(muserDetailsService);
        JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(createJwtDecoder());
        return new ProviderManager(
            daoAuthenticationProvider,
            jwtAuthenticationProvider
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> getMyJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        return new MyJwtConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_MYTHICAL_USER > ROLE_GRANDPARENT > ROLE_PARENT > ROLE_CHILD");
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler getMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    public JwtAuthenticationConverter oldJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
        //This line throws the class cast exception but then
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("authorities");
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

}

@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jwt")
public class JwtPropHolder {

    private String key;
    private String algorithm;
    private Integer randomByteSize;


    public SecretKey getSecretKey() {
        return new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algorithm);
    }



}

The class that generates the token:
@Service
public class JwsService {

    @Autowired
    private JwtPropHolder jwtPropHolder;

    private JWSObject jwsObject;

    private String jwsSerialised;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public void createJws(Map<String, Object> claims) throws JOSEException {
        jwsObject = new JWSObject(
            new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.parse(jwtPropHolder.getAlgorithm())),
            new Payload(claims)
        );
            
        JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner(jwtPropHolder.getSecretKey());
        jwsObject.sign(signer);
        jwsSerialised = jwsObject.serialize();
    }

    public void createJwsFromClaimsSet(Map<String, Object> claims) throws JOSEException {
        JWTClaimsSet.Builder builder = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder();
        if (claims.containsKey("sub")){
            builder.claim("sub", claims.get("sub"));
        }
        if (claims.containsKey("iss")){
            builder.claim("iss", claims.get("iss"));
        }
        if (claims.containsKey("exp")){
            builder.claim("exp", claims.get("exp"));
        }
        if (claims.containsKey("iat")) {
            builder.claim("iat", claims.get("iat"));
        }
        builder.claim("authorities", claims.get("authorities"));



    }

    /**
     * Returns the string token
     * @return
     */
    public String getJwsSerialised() {
        return jwsSerialised;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the whole JWSObject
     * @return
     */
    public JWSObject getJwsObject() {
        return jwsObject;
    }


}

The class that does the login and returns the token:
   @RestController
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticationApi {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private JwsService jwsService;

    public AuthenticationApi(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwsService jwsService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwsService = jwsService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) throws JOSEException {
        Authentication authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(
            loginRequest.username(),
            loginRequest.password()
        );

        Authentication authenticated = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
        /**
         * I can't just pass a date,
         * And all time related things need to be in numeric seconds format as per JWT spec,
         * So I am converting LocalDateTime and then working with it as its more accurate,
         * And does not have that one hour discrepency
         * First I will create the LocalDateTimes, so I can send these back to the client,
         * Then I will create the seconds version and send it in the JWT:
         */
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime expiry = LocalDateTime.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        Long nowInSeconds = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        Long expiryInSeconds = expiry.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();

        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("authorities", authenticated.getAuthorities());
        claims.put("name",  authenticated.getName());
        claims.put("exp", expiryInSeconds);
        claims.put("iat", nowInSeconds);

        jwsService.createJws(claims);

        return new LoginResponse(
            jwsService.getJwsSerialised(),
            jwsService.getJwsObject(),
            authenticated,
            now,
            expiry
        );

    }

}

Since i am using LocalDateTime, i am not getting the one hour difference, but it just does not expire ?
I looked through the source code and I can't seem to find any code that validates the expiry date




Using ZonedDateTime / OffsetDateTime instead of LocalDateTime or instant solves the problem.
The Instant class goes one hour behind and does not take into account the daylight saving time in Europe/London from where I am doing this.
This should not be taken into account when working with timestamps, but for some reason it was not working when i was creating timestamps out of the Instant class.
But it works with ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime
@PostMapping("/login")
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) throws JOSEException {
        Authentication authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(
            loginRequest.username(),
            loginRequest.password()
        );

        Authentication authenticated = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
        
        OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now();
        OffsetDateTime expiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        Long nowInSeconds = now.toEpochSecond();
        Long expiryInSeconds = expiry.toEpochSecond();

        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("authorities", authenticated.getAuthorities());
        claims.put("sub",  authenticated.getName());
        claims.put("exp", expiryInSeconds);
        claims.put("iat", nowInSeconds);

        jwsService.createJws(claims);

        return new LoginResponse(
            jwsService.getJwsSerialised(),
            jwsService.getJwsObject(),
            authenticated,
            now,
            expiry
        );

    }


The timestamps validations are probably done by JwtTimestampValidator (this is what NimbusJwtDecoder, the default JWT decoder uses by default). The default "clock skew" is set to 60 seconds, so the access token shouldn't be accepted more than a minute after the token expiration.
If you expect Spring Security oauth2ResourceServer to be useful, you should be using OAuth2.
If you were using OAuth2, the tokens would be issued (and signed) by an authorization server (not by your resource server). And yes, an OAuth2 authorization server issuing JWT tokens should expose a public key for resource servers to validate access tokens (and clients to validate ID tokens if the authorization server complies with OpenID).
Also, a reasonably secured authorization server should rotate its keys and other actors fetch the new public key each time it rotates.
So start by learning some OAuth2 essentials and choose an authorization server (preferably one complying with OIDC like Keycloak, Auth0, Amazon Cognito, Spring Authorization Server, or one of the many other solutions).
Using JWTs as user sessions has several issues (it prevents from instantly revoking access and is discouraged by the Spring team for security reasons). If exposing your backend to a single-page or mobile application, you should instead have a look at the OAuth2 BFF pattern (a BFF is stateful, but Spring Session is there if you need horizontal scaling).

Hi, Thank you for this but it doesn't answer the q.  If I am not using the OAuth2 protocol, I should not use the resource server is that your point ? Yes i will be learning that next, but for this project I am not implementing any OAuth, I just have a single backend so there is no need for a seperate Authorization server, I will be learning OAuth properly in the near future. This is just an alternative to using external libraries like jjwt etc...  I just want to create a simple backend that validates a token

Have I not created the tokens properly ? The point behind this is to create a stateless backend that i could use with a JavaScript SPA front-end like react, I know I can use cookies, but what if I had another front-end like a Mobile. And i only have a single backend, I thought I could use this instead of the jjwt library as I have seen in other tutorials. I guess I could use JWT's outside by just using the library instead of the resource server

Oh okay thanks, I will look into it, But i checked the docs about the clock skew, i set it to 0, but the tokens are being validated even 10, 15 minutes after expiry, why might this be ? I have seen so many tutorials showing this pattern using external libraries to create and verify jwt's at the same server, I guess i don't need to learn this unless doing OAuth2 ? If this is true , then Its fine,

You can hardly imagine how many tutorials are wrong about Bearer authorization...
